# Simple ng-Route not working in ng-View

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes, ngroute

I have a simple example in which the default one.html must be visible by ng-Route, but instead I am getting an error.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src= "angularScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-view=""></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

angularScript.js

```
//App Declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ng-Route'] );

//Controllers 
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

});

//Routers 
app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/one', {
        title: 'one',
        controller: 'oneCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'one.shtml'
    })  
    .when('/two', {
        title: 'two',
        controller: 'twoCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'two.shtml'
    })  
    .when('/three', {
        title: 'three',
        controller: 'threeCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'three.shtml'
    })  
    .otherwise({
        title: 'one',
        redirectTo: '/one'
    });
});
```

one.html

```
This is one
```

I am putting dependency of ng-Route and trying to get the default one.html content in the page at div with ng-view but I am getting the following error on my console:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

Comment: use <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script> for specific detail about error

Comment: you didn't specify controller anywhere

Comment: var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'] );
app.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code in your angularjs Script

```
    //App Declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'] );

//Controllers 
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

});
app.controller('oneCtrl', function($scope) {

});
//Routers 
app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/one', {
        title: 'one',
        controller: 'oneCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'one.shtml'
    })  
    .when('/two', {
        title: 'two',
        controller: 'twoCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'two.shtml'
    })  
    .when('/three', {
        title: 'three',
        controller: 'threeCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'three.shtml'
    })  
    .otherwise({
        title: 'one',
        redirectTo: '/one'
    });
});
```

You need to specify oneCtrl in controller as well as ngRoute

Comment: use angular.js instead of angular.min.js for developing purpose. It will show you more specific error description